# Change status of add to cart button depends on quantity Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

on woocommerce site I would like when the product has 0 qty to show the add to cart button disabled and not disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/classes/WC-Product.html#method_get_stock_quantity

You can use the `get_stock_quantity` method of `WC_Product` to check the available count of your product.

```
global $product;

if ( $product && $product->get_stock_quantity() > 0 ) {
    // your current button
} else {
    // disabled button
}
```

For loop, you can use the hooks from [this template](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/loop/add-to-cart.php) and for a single page from [these](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/tree/master/templates/single-product/add-to-cart).